# Which method when navigation bar "back" button clicked?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am using UINavigationController to push and pop a view.

I used `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myView animated:YES]` to push in a view. Then I clicked the top-left back button to go back, I am getting error:

```
*** -[NSCFDictionary superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1451a0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1451a0'
```

I am wondering which method `-popViewController` is calling when the back button is called.
Whether this error happens in the first view or the second view which is pushed in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Back button should be called -popViewControllerAnimated:. However, it sounds like you've got a class over-release bug here. Basically, you've got a view, which is being assigned somehwere. This view is just an address in memory. At some point, you're releasing this view all the way down to a retainCount of 0. When this happens, the view is dealloc'd. At some point after this, an NSDictionary is being created *with the same memory address* as your earlier, now deallocated, view. Now something is trying to send your view a message, but it's no longer there, instead, there's an NSDictionary there. It says something along the lines of: [view superview], but *view* is now pointing to a dictiinary, which doesn't respond to superview.

Bottom line: check your retain/release/autorelease calls, and make sure you're not over-releasing one of your views (or view controllers, though that's less likely).

Comment: Per Ben's suggestion, I rechecked the code, it appears that I have a local UIButton, which was created and released in the method. After I changed that local variable UIButton to instance variable and only release in dealloc, issue appears gone.

Thanks Ben